# what is happening when i run this code line?

Tags: matlab, filters, image-processing, matrix

I have the following MATLAB code:

```
x=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9;];
u=(0:255)/(255-1).^1.05;
x2=u(x+1)
```

when I run this code I get the following as a result in `x2`:

```
x2 =

0.0030    0.0060    0.0090
0.0119    0.0149    0.0179
0.0209    0.0239    0.0269
```

what is happening when I call this `line x2=u(x+1)`? and how to write it mathematically?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: `x2=[u(2) u(3) u(4); u(5) u(6) u(7); u(8) u(9) u(10)]`

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the values of

```
u(2),...,u(10)
```

in a $3\times 3$ matrix with the shape of the index matrix $x$. This could be written simply as $$x2_{(i,j)}= u (x_{(i,j)}+1),\;(i,j)\in[1,2,3]\times[1,2,3]\,. $$

For further matrix shape conversions, you can have a look at [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) or [matricization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matricization), and you can find notations in chapter 3.4 Matricization of a tensor of [Multilinear operators for higher-order decompositions](http://www.sandia.gov/~tgkolda/pubs/pubfiles/SAND2006-2081.pdf), T. Kolda, 2006.